Setting a state based on another state which is updated using a callback
I'm using an event handler for a part of a component that needs to be removed afterwards, so the handler function can't change, otherwise its reference would change and I wouldn't be able to remove the listener.
Therefore, when setting a state inside the event handler, I must use an updater function to set the state, like so:
const handleMouseDown = () => {
    const handleMouseMove = () => {

        // Using updater function to update state
        setValues((values) => {
             const newValue = calculateNewValue(values);
             const newValues = [...values, newValue];
             return newValues;
        });
    };

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
}

The issue is that I need to set another state based on newValues, and I want to take advantage of React's batching so everything gets updated after one re-render. The following code works but it triggers two re-renders:
const handleMouseDown = () => {
    const handleMouseMove = () => {

        setValues((values) => {
            const newValue = calculateNewValue(values);
            const newValues = [...values, newValue];
            
            // Works, but triggers 2 re-renders: one because values 
            // changed, and another one because otherValues changed
            setOtherValues(calculateOtherValues(newValues));

            return newValues;
        });
    };
    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
};

The following won't work for my purposes:
Storing newValues before using setValues doesn't work as this is wrapped inside an event handler that isn't re-instantiated on every render, as I need to be able to remove it afterwards as I said in the beginning. This means that using values will reference its old contents (it will reference the state it had when the handler was created):
const handleMouseDown = () => {
    const handleMouseMove = () => {

        // Doesn't work because values will always reference the state 
        // it had when this function was created.
        const newValue = calculateNewValue(values);
        const newValues = [...values, newValue];
        
        setValues(newValues);
        setOtherValues(calculateOtherValues(newValues));
    };

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
};

Not using states. To simplify the problem I have used calculateOtherValues instead of pasting all of my logic. This immediately leads to the question: Why use a state when it can be calculated off of values ? Well, in this particular handler, otherValues can be and is calculated from values, but this isn't the case in one of my other handlers, where values needs to be calculated off of otherValues, so I need to keep it store as a state.
I'm trying to find a way to get it working without using an extra re-render like in the second code example.
Edit: Fixing typo and adding a bit more context:
The component I'm making is a custom slider that has multiple handles/thumbs and is designed to select percentages rather than the thumbs positions themselves. So, if you wanted to distribute votes for certain candidates for example, you can move the handles and get a very visual representation of the percentages each candidate gets.

The event handlers are structured in such a way that when the user clicks on one of these handles, the document starts listening for mouse movement. I add the listener to the document and not the handle because I want the user to be able to move the mouse outside of the handle (which is small) and continue dragging the handle.
The document also starts listening for mouse release, and when that happens it removes the aforementioned listeners.
It is key that the listener functions keep the same reference so I can remove them after mouse release. I have seen this event nesting behaviour in some other similar components online, but I of course welcome any suggestions :)
I understand it's not best practice to do this, but I don't think that's what causing my issue. I just need to find a workaround or re-think my states so that I can update both states using an updater function, and trigger just one re-render.

Would adding an AbortSignal to your event listener help? Then you only need the AbortController to remove the event listener:
var controller = new AbortController();
var action = () => console.log('Hello!');
addEventListener('click', action, { signal: controller.signal });
controller.abort();


This question lacks context but I see a red flag (clean up listener inside listener callback) which should be done inside a useEffect (see here an example https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables). Maybe this triggers unwanted setState calles

You try to register  a handler to mouseup via . addEvenetListener (typo in EvenEt).

Thanks for the comments. I added a bit more context and fix the typo. I'm looking into the AbortController idea now.

Hey @TGekko , your suggestion worked and solved my problem. If you want you can post it as an answer and I'll mark it as solved. Thanks!!

I'm glad that my suggestion was useful to you!

It appears as though your problem could be solved by adding an AbortSignal to your event listener.
Using an AbortController, you can remove a specific event listener at any time. That way you won't have to attempt to store the function for the listener:
var controller = new AbortController();
var action = () => console.log('Hello!');
addEventListener('click', action, { signal: controller.signal }); 

To remove the event listener, you need only abort the listener using the controller:
controller.abort();

Hopefully this is helpful in solving the issue involving your changing listener function.
